# Connect Raspberry Pi to MacBook air over USB ethernet adapter and use the WiFi connection on the Mac

Tags: ethernet, headless, connection

My setup = Raspberry Pi + Keyboard + Mouse, connected to a MacBook air via a USB Ethernet adapter. On the MacBook air, internet sharing is on to allow the USB Ethernet device use the WIFI connection to the outside world.

On the Raspberry Pi the Wheezy, and some modification to the `/etc/network/interfaces`. Static IP method is used.

Result:

- SSH from MacBook air to Raspberry Pi Works.
- Ping to MacBook air USB adapter IP address works.
- Ping to Raspberry IP address works.
- Midori access to the outside world (all the way through the WiFi !) works. - Requires SquidMan.

Ping from the terminal (SSH on Mac, or a terminal from the Raspberry Pi GUI) to any outside address (tried 8.8.8.8 and others) does not work, returns
`Unknown Host`.

Therefore things like `apt-get` does not work … Hence … Stuck!

Any suggestions would be well appreciated.

Comment: How to connect Raspberry Pi to MAC with Ethernet to USB port You can see as this link:
http://topboxbox.blogspot.com/?m=1

Comment: When troubleshooting cases like this ping is unsufficient, use ´traceroute´.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the DNS namespace? 'sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf' and change it to the DNS of you Mac. In my case,  it was the default (192.168.1.1)

Comment: If you ping an IP adr.like 8.8.8.8 , there is no need for DNS since its not used!